# Rearrange child subtab in Netsuite

Tags: parent-child, record, netsuite

I have a requirement to have two custom record types under parent subtab arrange in order. I used parent-child relationship but the arrangement of the child subtab is something I couldnt customize. 'test one' and 'test two' are my custom record types, and Parent is item fulfillment record.
I want 'test one' to come first and then 'test two'.
I tried adding a new Subtab via customization under translation and this order customization is not available in netsuite. Am i missing anything?
Please help.
[image]

Comment: Not sure why you want this. Does it really matter? One solution what I can see is just go to both the records and remove the `record is parent` then edit it first for `test one record` and then `test two record`.

Comment: Yes it matters as that order is also under requirement. :) 
unfortunately, That removing and adding again  din't work :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit the record
2. Click "customize" then "customize form" in the top right of the form
3. Navigate to "Lists" then select "Communication"
4. You can drag and drop your prefered order from this screen
5. Name then save the custom entry form
6. You can then manually select this form for the record or set it as the default form

Comment: My child record 'test one' and 'test two' is not under 'Lists'. :(

Answer (score 0):

If a field is visible on the form, then it appears somewhere in the Custom Entry Form screen.  Which tab it's on depends on the type of field.  It could be under Lists, or Fields, or elsewhere.  Look for it.

When you find it, use the Field Group dropdown to move the field between the main view and sub tabs, and drag/drop the field to change its top-down display order.  The drag handle looks like `⋮⋮`.

Comment: Parent child relationship setup is totally in a different page where I create custom record "test_one" and "test_two". This is no related to custom form setup. :(